# Tweaking rendering of thumbnail images in galleria

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, galleria

I am working on the classic theme of Galleria to display a gallery. Here the requirement is to display the thumbnails in two row with the images in following order with a horizontal scroller if the thumbnails list div width increases more than 24.

```
1 3 5 7 9  11 13 15 17 19 21 23 ..

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 ..
```

For if the images are less than 24 and more than 12 then the order should be rendered in two rows as :-

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

13 14 15 ..
```

For if the images is less than 12 the images should be rendered in a single row as :-

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7...
```

Presently what I have done is I am using css3 column property to do this using different classes on the basis of image counts. This is working in all browsers but in IE8.

So, is there any substitute for css3 column property for IE8 or less. Or some better way to implement the stuff that works fine in IE as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct substitute for columns in IE8.  To fix this, you are going to need to detect the number of thumbnails, and then assign classes appropriately, and write custom css classes.

So you could add a "columns" class to the thumbnails holder and then write the css you already have to make columns display correctly (possibly with tweaks) and then another class to have a different display.

That said, galleria really doesn't have the easiest API for this.

Comment: I did the same , using javascript I detected the number of thumbnails in different scenarios and assisgned different classes to them and then styled them easily. Also the client is happy with the work. But now I feel that if I would have used some polyfills like CSS3PIE to support the css property in IE8 this would have been more easier.

Comment: Vote me up if it was helpful :)